# Two scala specs file need two different enviorments

Tags: scala, spray, specs2

I have Scala project in which I have used `Specs2` for test cases. 
In that specs I have two specs2 file lets say `spec1` and `spec2`.

The `spec1` requires production env to run the test cases and `specs2` requires dev environment to run test cases.

I get environment specific values from configuration file and that at a time I can configure one value for environment either 'prod' or 'dev'.

So I have set env as prod in config file my `dev` test case fails and vice versa , hence the build failed.
So what should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you running tests in production environment?

Comment: @RobertUdah , actually I am not running them in prod, env but I have some requirement where I should user prod. env for some values.

Comment: You need to restructure your code to accept as an input any `Configuration` and inject the desired one in each test.